# How to Use a custom Heritaged User as authentication in Django 1.9?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm somewhat new in Django, and I'm trying to extract user info from a form, the problem arises when I try to save that form info into the database, as the user info it gets is from default Users model, but the model being saved ("Mensaje") has a Foreign Key relationship with the extended User model I use (called "Usuario"), so the engine fails when I try to put the form info into the model.

I try to touch as less as possible of the default options for compatibility sake, but I can't find the right answer for my problem as most questions/answers are outdated. Here's my code:

```
#app/models.py
class Usuario (models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    segundos = models.IntegerField()
    id_ciudad = models.ForeignKey(Ciudad,related_name="Fk1_usuario_ciudad")


    def __str__(self):
        cadenaMinutos = self.user.first_name + ', tiene acumulados ' + str(int(self.segundos/60))
        return cadenaMinutos


class Mensaje (models.Model):
    tit_msj = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    descripcion_msj = models.TextField()
    email = models.EmailField()
    f_msj= models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    id_usr = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, related_name="Fk1_mensaje_usr")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tit_msj
```

The view that is giving me a headache:

```
#views.py
def contacto(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        formulario = FormularioContacto(request.POST)
        if formulario.is_valid():
            mensaje = formulario.save(commit=False)
            if request.user.is_authenticated():
                mensaje.id_usr = request.user
                mensaje.save()
            else:
                mensaje.save()
            return redirect('exchange.views.gracias', correo=mensaje.email)
    else:
        formulario = FormularioContacto()
        return render(request, 'base/contacto.html',{'form' : formulario})
```

And finally the form that the view is using:

```
#forms.py
class FormularioContacto(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Mensaje
        fields = ('tit_msj', 'descripcion_msj', 'email',)
```

I think the best thing to do would be to make the extended User model ("Usuario") the model used for authentication, but I'm stuck here.

For anyone interested, here's the error the engine throw:

```
Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: admin>>": "Mensaje.id_usr" must be a "Usuario" instance.
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `mensaje.id_usr = request.user` to `mensaje.id_usr = request.user.usuario` will fix the error.

Comment: Thanks a lot, just what I needed, I feel embarrased for not seeing something so obvious, I still need to learn a lot about Django.